# Send Soap Request and capture the Response

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, soap

I am trying to build WPF program to create Soap requests as xml files according to the WSDL which is added as service reference.
The problem is that I could not configure the proxy class to use that xml file and send it as a request as well as receiving the response. It gives me an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: APPLICATION ERROR

```
public string returnSerializedxml(object input)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(input.GetType());

    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, input);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ConsignmentEndpointClient proxy = new ConsignmentEndpointClient();
    save sv = new save();
    saveResponse response = new saveResponse();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(PATH);
    response= proxy.save(sv);  /*Here occur the exception*/

    try
    {
        Output.Text = "Response : \n" + returnSerializedxml(response);     
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Output.Text = "Error in Request : \n" + error;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing the code down to ignore the objects that aren't interacting with the webservice call gives:

```
ConsignmentEndpointClient proxy = new ConsignmentEndpointClient();
save sv = new save();
response= proxy.save(sv);  /*Here occur the exception*/
```

Without knowing what the webservice is expecting, it *looks* like you're trying to save a brand new object, that has not been changed in any way (which may, or may not, be a valid thing to do). You're not handling the exception that it is throwing, which is why it is unhandled - you could simply move that to be within the call into the scope of the `try` block, so something more like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ConsignmentEndpointClient proxy = new ConsignmentEndpointClient();
        save sv = new save();

        throw new NotImplementedExcetpion("This probably needs to be associated with your sv object in some way, or just removed altogether");

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(PATH);
        saveResponse response = proxy.save(sv);  /*Here occur the exception*/

        Output.Text = "Response : \n" + returnSerializedxml(response);     
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Output.Text = "Error in Request : \n" + error;
    }
}
```